# How does LeapMotion specify which hand is left and which is right?

Tags: python, leap-motion

I am new to Leap Motion, and am playing with the sample code in Python (also new to Python). I am trying to get the a few pieces of information about the left and right hands and fingers (pitch, roll, yaw...etc). It is important that I know which is left and which is right. I can pull out hand information using frame.hands but I am confused about which hand is which. For example is frame.hands[0] always the left hand, the  leftmost hand, or is it arbitrary? I am also confused about why it sometimes thinks there are more than 2 hands. Is frame.hands[0] the same hand from frame to frame? If not, is there a good way to track a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any guarantee of index order in the `HandList`, although you can use e.g. `rightmost` to [select on a spatial basis](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Python/Guides/Leap_Tracking.html#hands):

```
    hands = frame.hands

    rightmost = hands.rightmost
```

However, to reproduce their note verbatim:

> Note that the the `leftmost()` and `rightmost()` functions only identify which hand is farthest to the left or right. The functions do not identify which hand is the right or left hand.

If you want to track a hand from frame to frame, you can use its `Hand.id`; see [the documentation](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Python/Guides/Leap_Frames.html#using-ids-to-track-entities-across-frames):

```
handID = rightmost.id

hand = frame.hand(handID)
```

Comment: This is no longer true. More recent version of the API do identify left vs. right hands.

Comment: @CharlesWard great; could you write an answer showing how?

Comment: There already is one (below) -- I just noticed that this older answer was the "accepted" version and wanted to clarify that the API had changed between the times the two answers were submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can look to the leap motion api reference: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/api/Leap.Hand.html?proglang=python#Leap.Hand.is_left

As you san see on this page there are such booleans to indicate that if the hand is right or left:

```
if hand.is_right:
    # .. Do right handed stuff

hand_name = "Left hand" if hand.is_left else "Right hand"
```